# Unable to inspect in appium inspector and the appium get crashing , while launching the appium inspector

Tags: appium, inspector

1. I have installed appium 1.3.7 version in mac machine.
2. I have started appium server for android app in android device.
3. In android device, the app get installed and opened successfully.
4. I have clicked the show inspector button and then I can able to see the inspector screen and then my appium inspector get crashed.
5. I have attached the screen shot below for reference.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Appium Inspector crashes with device having Android OS < 5.0, upgrade device os to 5.0, it should be okay. This issue is already logged with appium.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this `forceMjsonwp : true` in capabilities resolved it for me.